# Wordpress friendly URL for image directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

There's often a need to use images in the Wordpress theme folder for other uses (for instance in an email).

These URLs take the form; 
`http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/image.jpg` or
`http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/path-to-my-image/image.jpg`

What sort of redirect in htaccess would I need to use a simple url 
`http://example.com/images/image.jpg`?

I am, of course, assuming `http://example.com/images` isn't used for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} images/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/%1 [L,R=303]
```